# Floating bed design review

Tags: wood, furniture, design

First time here.
I've decided to make my own floating bed, I've watched a few videos, but one feature I'd like to include is storage, and for that, I've added a sort of a lid in the middle of the big frame.

I've only done a table, so I'm a beginner, and I'd like to check with somebody more skilful if there's something conceptually wrong with my design. For example, I'm doubting if the small frame (the base) is big enough to avoid the bed from flipping if you stand/sit on the border.

I'll upload a bunch of images but let me know if you'd like to see the sketchup file (bear in mind that I'm also a beginner there)

The small frame is 100x140 and the big frame on to is 180x200

They are built mostly with 63x160 wood beams. [Like this](https://www.sleiderink.nl/vuren-geschaafd-63x160).

[image: bed frame without the lid]
[image: bed frame with the lid]
[image: small frame]
[image: big frame]
[image: From the bottom]

More dimensions

[image]

Comment: Welcome to WSE.    When you recess the base you are basically creating a teeter-totter or fulcrum. Whether the bed will tilt when you sit at the edges will depend upon the distribution of dead load (mattress) and live load (how much do the users sitting on the edge weigh). It would also be helpful if we had a few more dimensions.  I see three frames in total. How wide is the top perimeter platform, what is its overall dimensions and how is it secured to the other frames?

Comment: I am also curious about the storage feature.  If you put a mattress on the top surface accessing the storage area will not be easy.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! I've updated the question with more dimensions! I'm actually thinking the top platform is too thick so I'll probably change that.

Indeed, yes, its hard to access. The idea behind that storage space is just to not "waste" it, or to gain that. I think I'll use to store coats and duvets during summer, for example, something I don't need daily (or even monthly) but for seasons. – 


And I'll secure the pieces like they did here https://youtu.be/w1IAAps54SI?t=1308

Comment: I could also make the base bigger, of course, but I don't know how far I can push it without loosing the floating effect

Comment: You could easily move that cavity around to the edge and make a sliding or wheeled drawer that slides into it.

Comment: Checking out the youtube link you provided in the comments, it appears that your design is attempting to duplicate his. If it worked for him then it should work for you.  As Volfram K suggest in his answer you may have to actually test the design to be sure.  Worse case if it tilts is that you have to make the bottom frame a bit bigger.  Remember that the appearance of floating is mostly from eyelevel at the max distance you will view it from.  In addition, you can make the bottom material and finish match the floor,  which will fool the eye even if the base is partially visible.

Comment: @Ashlar, I don't see access to that central bit of storage any sort of issue since the mattress can be easily lifted to stand on one edge, or even better if there's room to just slide it off..... at least not here in Europe where mattresses don't average at 100lb or more (>45kg) o_O

Comment: Jorge, I wanted to mention something you might have overlooked — if you make your slats easily removable (e.g. by mounting with magnets, or they can just be floating) all the other cubbyholes created by the framing can be available storage space too :-)

Comment: That's true! @Graphus that's a good idea, but then I'm not really sure how to attach the top structure, as I was thinking of attaching it to the slats and then the slats to the frame.

Comment: @Ashlar yes, I think I'll make the base a just bit bigger, in the room there's not space enough to look at the bed from really far anyway, and then test it

Comment: Well the slats definitely don't need to be firmly fixed to upper frame for the stability of the latter. As long as the mitred pieces are firmly attached to the base (plenty of screws is probably the way to go there) that'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm doubting if the small frame (the base) is big enough to avoid the bed from flipping if you stand/sit on the border.

Do not stand on the border!

For adult sitting on edge this looks ok to me, weight of bed base + matress should be sufficient for bed to be stable. But without knowing person's weight it is guesswork.

You will have to build it and test to be sure. Sit on edge, if the bed does lift on other side there are easy fixes possible:

- add weight to base - bags of sand, bricks, concrete blocks
- screw to floor! 2 screws maybe all you need.

Comment: Adding the weight is a very good idea I think! That could fix it if when I test the bed it does a barrelroll